# Thevenin circuit, basic laws are confusing me

Tags: thevenin

So the question is to find the equivalent Thevenin circuit, I did solve it using Nodal analysis, now the answer in the book is -5V while I got 5V, so it's still the correct answer, right ?

[image]

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong about +/- voltage, so we are considering V(ab), so +5V means (a) is 5V above (b) and -5V means (b) is 5V below (a) ? 
And why in my solution I do get +V ? Is it because of my current direction assumptions ?

Comment: You might have confused yourself by labelling the voltage at an inner node as \$V_{TH}\$ when the thevenin voltage (what we would normally label as \$V_{TH}\$) would be the voltage between the nodes labelled 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

> considering V(ab), so +5V means (a) is 5V above (b)

Yes.

> and -5V means (b) is 5V below (a) ?

No, that would be the same as (a) being 5 V above (b). It means b is 5 V above a.

By convention \$V_{ab}\$ means \$V_a - V_b\$, so if \$V_{ab} > 0\$, it means \$V_a > V_b\$ and if  \$V_{ab} < 0\$, it means \$V_b > V_a\$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so is the answer +5V still correct? And the other thing is what change in my solution would get -5V ?

Comment: \$V_{TH}\$ as labeled in your diagram is 5 V when the output is open circuit, but that is not the Thevenin equivalent voltage for this circuit.

Comment: Right, I assumed Vth has the same voltage as V(ab) but I think that is not the case here because of the 10V source. So then Nodal analysis won't work in this case ? So I should probably just resort to either KVL or Superposition.

Comment: You should be able to find the open-circuit voltage between a and b by inspection after you've found your \$V_{TH}\$.

Comment: OK so there is a voltage drop of -10V then there is a voltage rise of 5V giving an overall voltage drop of -5V. I do usually tend to over think things and confuse myself in the process. Now what's bugging me is that for example in Mesh analysis I did always consider - to + terminal as voltage rise and + to - terminal as drop. Now if I do that in here, again I get a +5V as the answer

Comment: @BigRed, it does take a bit of practice to get to where it's easy to manage the sign convention for mesh analysis in your head. There are many other questions about this topic on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated Rth as seen by the red 10V battery. The calculation is ok. You should calculate Vth also as seen by the red 10V battery - its the voltage fom a to b when the red battery is removed. The result will be -5V.